# Changing a Meteor collection subscription for all clients

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-publications, meteor-collections

I am developing a webapp in which I'd need one client, associated with the *admin*, to trigger an event (e.g., a new value selected in a dropdown list) which in turns will tell all the other connected clients to change the subscription, possibly using a parameter, i.e., the new selected value.

Something along the lines of

```js
Template.bid.events
  "change .roles": (e, tpl) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    role = tpl.$("select[name='role']").val()
    Meteor.subscribe role
```

Of course this works for the current client only.
One way I thought would be keeping a separate collection that points a the current collection to be used, so the clients can programmatically act on that. It feels cumbersome, thou.

Is there a Meteor-way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In meteor, whenever you have a problem that sounds like: "I need to synchronize data across clients", you should use a collection. I realize it seems like overkill just to send one piece of data, but I assure you it's currently the path of least resistance.

There are ways you can expose pseudo-collections which don't actually write to mongo, but for your use case that really sounds like overkill - `new Mongo.Collection` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to setup a simple line of communication between connected clients and the server. It doesn't store data in MongoDB. Just let all connected clients listen to a stream and switch subscriptions when a new message comes in with the subscription name. Make sure only your client associated to your admin can push messages to the stream.

Available package: https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/streams

Examples: http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/